# How to make a private delay function in javascript es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'd like to make a private class function which delays 100 ms, but I can't quite get the syntax right.

Below is a short ES6 class which checks to see if the user has certain permissions. I cache the result in `#permissions` which is an array. I only want to expose one method: `has` which takes a string parameter and checks it against that list of permissions.

```
class Permission {
  #permissions = [];

  #started = false;

  async init() {
    this.#started = true;
    const res = await axios.get('/user/permissions');
    this.#permissions = res.data.permissions;
    this.#started = false;
  }

  static #delay(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async has(perm) {
    while (!this.#permissions.length) {
      if (!this.#started) {
        this.init();
      }
      await this.#delay(100);
    }
    return this.#permissions.includes(perm);
  }
}
```

What I've tried:

1. When I remove the `static` keyword, the linter complains that it should be a static function since `this` isn't in the function.
2. When I put `static` back in, the linter is silent, but I get a runtime error: `TypeError: Receiver must be class Permission`

Comment: Isn't is just a matter of calling the static method: `await Permission.#delay(100);`?

Comment: Your `init()` method is `async`, but when you call it you do not `await` the result. I realize it doesn't *have* a result, but that means that your delay can finish before the axios call in `init()` completes.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen right, because `delay()` is a static method, you can't call it via `this`, you call it with the class name, as the error (somewhat obscurely) says.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah. Don't know if it satisfies the linter though.

Comment: Don't use a delay which is a hack and not reliable.  Just save the promise from the `axios.get()` in the instance data and use that promise in `.has()` to ALWAYS be able to get the value.  Also, you need error handling for what happens if the `axios.get()` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using a delay to check on the pending state of a promise. Instead rely on the event of a promise getting resolved. If you still want to introduce a delay before firing a next HTTP request, you can still await a delay, but it should not serve to check upon a variable that gets written when a promise resolves.

This also means you shouldn't store the `permissions` as a field, as you should listen to a promise state change to get those permissions -- every time!

Here is how it could be done:

```
class Permission {
  #promise
  
  constructor() {
    this.#promise = this.#init(); // Immediately initiate the request
  }
  
  async #init() {
    while (true) { // Retry loop -- in case the response is an empty array
      const response = await axios.get('/user/permissions');
      if (response?.data?.permissions?.length) return response.data.permissions;
      await Permission.#delay(100); // Optional -- if you want a cooldown
    }
  }

  static #delay(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async has(perm) {
    return (await this.#promise).includes(perm); // Always await this promise
  }
}
```

And of course, `has` returns a promise, so the caller should always treat it that way.

Comment: Awesome. This worked. The only tweaks were that the linter still complained that #init should be static, so I did that. Thanks @robbycornellisen for explaining the error.